# JavaCC: Is it possible to use POSIX Character classes to represent Unicode strings

Tags: regex, javacc

I am able to use the POSIX Class : \p{L} to represent all possible unicode letters in the Java Pattern class.

However I am not able to use the same regex pattern in javacc.

I tried defining a token as follows

<#LET: "\p{L}" >

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

JavaCC currently doesn't support character classes.

Comment: What are my options for doing the above in JavaCC ?

Comment: I would write a java program to spit out the correct range of characters.  Then you can manually copy that into the .jj file.

Comment: Or become a contributor and add the feature to the next version.